# Finding discrepancy between two data sets when setdiff is not working

Tags: r, set-difference

I have data for spot price and day-ahead price for hour 2 and hour 3. They are as below. They are from 2015-12-31 to 2011-01-01 all the way down.

```
> head(da2)
             Date Price Hour
43802 2015-12-31 12.56    2
43778 2015-12-30 23.59    2
43754 2015-12-29 17.07    2

> head(sp2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
         Date  Hour  Price
       <dttm> <chr>  <dbl>
1 2015-12-31     2  17.15
2 2015-12-30     2  26.23
3 2015-12-29     2  23.01

> head(da3)
             Date Price Hour
43803 2015-12-31 10.46    3
43779 2015-12-30 23.55    3
43755 2015-12-29 16.52    3

> head(sp3)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
        Date  Hour  Price
       <dttm> <chr>  <dbl>
1 2015-12-31     3  12.96
2 2015-12-30     3  25.65
3 2015-12-29     3  23.59
```

I tried to put da2$Price and sp2$Price together, and again the same for hour 3.

But unfortunately, I get this.

```
> rpdf2<-data.frame(da2$Date,da2$Price,sp2$Price)
Error in data.frame(da2$Date, da2$Price, sp2$Price) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1826, 1822

> rpdf3<-data.frame(da3$Date,da3$Price,sp3$Price)
Error in data.frame(da3$Date, da3$Price, sp3$Price) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1821, 1825
```

So I applied `> setdiff(paste(da2$Date),paste(sp2$Date))`
Then I found

```
          [1] "2014-03-30" "2013-03-31" "2012-03-25" "2011-03-27"
```

It was okay. But when I did `setdiff(paste(da3$Date),paste(sp3$Date))`, It shows me `character(0)`.
There must be 4 observations difference. But I cannot find those four. Can anyone help me with this situation? Thank you.

When `setdiff(da3$Date,sp3$Date)`

result is

[1] 16800.04 16799.04 16798.04 16797.04 16796.04 16795.04 16794.04 16793.04 16792.04 16791.04 16790.04 16789.04 16788.04 16787.04 16786.04 16785.04 16784.04
  [18] 16783.04 16782.04 16781.04 16780.04 16779.04 16778.04 16777.04 16776.04 16775.04 16774.04 16773.04 16772.04 16771.04 16770.04 16769.04 16768.04 16767.04
  [35] 16766.04 16765.04 16764.04 16763.04 16762.04 16761.04 16760.04 16759.04 16758.04 16757.04 16756.04 16755.04 16754.04 16753.04 16752.04 16751.04 16750.04
  [52] 16749.04 16748.04 16747.04 16746.04 16745.04 16744.04 16743.04 16742.04 16741.04 16740.04 16739.04 16738.04 16737.04 16736.04 16735.04 16734.04 16733.04
  [69] 16732.04 16731.04 16730.04 16729.04 16728.04 16727.04 16726.04 16725.04 16724.04 16723.04 16722.04 16721.04 16720.04 16719.04 16718.04 16717.04 16716.04
  [86] 16715.04 16714.04 16713.04 16712.04 16711.04 16710.04 16709.04 16708.04 16707.04 16706.04 16705.04 16704.04 16703.04 16702.04 16701.04 16700.04 16699.04

and so further.

Comment: What happens when you try the opposite: `setdiff(sp3$Date, da3$Date)`?

Also, I'm not sure why you need `paste` inside of `setdiff`

Comment: I have done it.. It does not quite work. If I do not use `paste` it shows weird numbers..

Comment: What does "not quite work" mean?  How are the numbers "weird"?

Comment: Please check my original post. I uploaded the result.

Answer (score 0):

One way (of many) to tackle this is instead of looking directly for the differences is to find a way to join your tables which will work regardless. To do so you simply need to generate a complete sequence of all dates from the first date on your list to the last, then left-join these to each of your daily and spot price data frames in turn. Missing date rows in each table will show as NA columns in the resulting joined table.

Example sequence, shortened to one month only for this exemplar. You'd start it at 2011-01-01 instead.

```
somedates = seq(as.Date("2015-12-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "day")
```

Generate some test data each with four randomly missed dates to simulate your da2, da3, sp2 and sp3 tables:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
da2 = data.frame(Date = sample(somedates, 27)) %>%
  mutate(hour = 2, price = 20)

set.seed(1)
da3 = data.frame(Date = sample(somedates, 27)) %>%
  mutate(hour = 3, price = 21)

set.seed(2)
sp2 = data.frame(Date = sample(somedates, 27)) %>%
  mutate(hour = 2, price = 19)

set.seed(3)
sp3 = data.frame(Date = sample(somedates, 27)) %>%
  mutate(hour = 3, price = 18)
```

**Joining the da2, da3, sp2 and sp3 tables**

With the test data generated, joining the tables to the complete sequence of dates (as a data frame) is straightforward. (NB I haven't replaced the joined column names with more meaningful versions in the result below).

```
all = 
  left_join(data.frame(Date = somedates), da2, by = "Date") %>%
  left_join(da3, by = "Date") %>%
  left_join(sp2, by = "Date") %>%
  left_join(sp3, by = "Date")
```

**Results from the test data joined**

```
>all
         Date hour.x price.x hour.y price.y hour.x.x price.x.x hour.y.y price.y.y
1  2015-12-01      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
2  2015-12-02      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
3  2015-12-03     NA      NA      3      21        2        19        3        18
4  2015-12-04      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
5  2015-12-05      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
6  2015-12-06      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
7  2015-12-07      2      20      3      21        2        19       NA        NA
8  2015-12-08      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
9  2015-12-09      2      20      3      21       NA        NA        3        18
10 2015-12-10      2      20      3      21       NA        NA        3        18
11 2015-12-11      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
12 2015-12-12     NA      NA      3      21        2        19        3        18
13 2015-12-13      2      20     NA      NA        2        19       NA        NA
14 2015-12-14      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
15 2015-12-15      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
16 2015-12-16      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
17 2015-12-17      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
18 2015-12-18      2      20     NA      NA        2        19        3        18
19 2015-12-19     NA      NA      3      21        2        19        3        18
20 2015-12-20      2      20     NA      NA       NA        NA        3        18
21 2015-12-21      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
22 2015-12-22      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
23 2015-12-23      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
24 2015-12-24      2      20      3      21        2        19       NA        NA
25 2015-12-25      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
26 2015-12-26      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
27 2015-12-27      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
28 2015-12-28      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
29 2015-12-29      2      20      3      21        2        19        3        18
30 2015-12-30      2      20      3      21       NA        NA        3        18
31 2015-12-31     NA      NA     NA      NA        2        19       NA        NA
```

*Edit* I note the numeric dates you posted as a result of your set join have a 0.04 time component as well as the whole-number date. You will need to add this to the date sequence to get the join to work. I have now tested this and without adding the time component you'd have to convert each date to a whole number. This can be done fairly simply though:

```
da2$Date = trunc.Date(da2$Date,  "days")
da3$Date = trunc.Date(da3$Date,  "days")
sp2$Date = trunc.Date(sp2$Date,  "days")
sp3$Date = trunc.Date(sp3$Date,  "days")
```

You'd do this before the joins.